# Weshalb spricht man vom "abgesicherten Modus" und nicht vom "sicheren Modus" in der EDV?

Tags: word-usage, adjective, meaning, technical-terminology

Seit ich vor Jahren zum ersten Mal auf den Begriff

> "starte den Computer im [**abgesicherten** Modus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abgesicherter_Modus)"

gestoßen bin, frage ich mich, welche besondere Bedeutung diesem Adjektiv zukommt, die dazu führte, dass man das englische Pendant *"safe mode"* nicht mit "sicherer Modus" übersetzt hat.

Im allgemeinem Sprachgebrauch wird "[absichern](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=absichern&submit_button=Suche&view=1)" beim Ergreifen von Maßnahmen zum Schutz vor Gefahren, oder im übertragenen Sinn auch zu Argumenten, die eine These untermauern, verwendet.

Diese Bedeutung könnte zwar auch in der EDV vorkommen, z.B. wenn man einen Computer mit Software gegen Viren *absichert*, oder das Betriebssystem vor unbefugten Schreib- oder Lesezugriffen schützt, aber genau das ist mit dem *abgesicherten Modus* **nicht** gemeint.

Gibt es demnach eine weitere Bedeutung in dem Adjektiv "abgesichert", die besser als "sicher" zum *"safe mode"* passt?

Nachdem dieser Begriff mittlerweile nicht nur für einen speziellen Betriebszustand von Windows benutzt wird, sondern auch bei anderen Betriebssystemen vorkommt, suche ich auch nach einer guten, allgemeinen Definition des *"abgesicherten Modus"*, die nicht nur Windows-spezifische Punkte aufführt und eine Verwendung außerhalb des Microsoft-Universums erlaubt.

Comment: Das trifft doch nicht nur auf die EDV zu. Es ist eine abgesichterte Unfallstelle und keine sichere Unfallstelle. Und wäre es der "sichere Modus" oder die "sichere Unfallstelle", würde ich fragen, ob es auch einen "unsicheren Modus" bzw. "unsichere Unfallstelle" gibt.

Comment: Ich habe immer angenommen das käme daher dass man im "safe mode" das Betriebssystem gegen Störungen durch fehlerhafte Treiber, schlechte programmierte 3rd Party-Software etc. absichert (habe dafür aber auch keine Quelle). Das man wie EM1 anmerkt einfach vermeiden wollte das Leute das Antonym bilden und ein normaler Start damit zum "unsicheren Modus" wird klingt aber wahrscheinlicher.

Comment: Und wenn du sagst, dass der abgesicherte Modus nicht zum Schutz vor z.b. Viren gilt, liegst du nur bedingt richtig. Immerhin werden viele Operationen, die bei einem normalen Startvorgang ausgeführt werden, unterlassen. Dadurch könnte man auch die Ausführung eines Viruses verhindern. Das ist zwar gar nicht die primäre Intention, aber es geht ja im Wesentlichen darum, dass eben möglichst wenig ausgeführt wird, was zu Fehlern (z.b. Bluescreen) führen kann.

Comment: Wenn ich etwas *absichere*, dann ergreife ich aktive Schutzmaßnahmen (Warndreieck an der Unfallstelle). Das bloße  Weglassen unsicherer Vorgänge würde ich nicht als *absichern* bezeichnen, auch wenn das Ganze danach vielleicht sicherer wird.

Comment: @Takkat+Em1: das ist an sich logisch, aber so ein Programm soll ja auch einen gewissen Appeal haben und da klingt "abgesichert" nun mal besser als "reduzierter", "mininmaler", "Not-Modus", "Basis-Modus" und was man sich sonst noch so ausdenken könnte, was die Idee das einfach nur was fehlt, transportiert. "Abgesichert" klingt gut, ist ähnlich wie Englisch "safe" und verhindert das Antonym "unsicher". Da spricht also echt viel dafür. Em1: super Theorie - mach' 'ne Antwort draus!!

Comment: @Takkat Es ist weniger ein Weglassen unsicherer Vorgänge, sondern eine Art Wegschließen gefährlicher Gegenstände oder  Absperren gefährlicher Orte.

Comment: Abgesichert heisst: ich habe etwas unternommen, um die Operation sicherer zu machen. Sicher heisst: es gibt keine Gefahrenstellen mehr. Das Englische ist also mit safe mode wohl etwas optimistischer, das Deutsche dagegen realistischer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bei Sprache ist man nie ganz sicher, aber ich möchte darauf aufmerksam machen, dass die verwendete Bezeichnung juristische Konsequenzen haben könnte. Wäre gut, wenn ein Jurist hier antwortet, aber die findet man auf StackXXX eher selten. Also versuche ich es.

**Sicherer Modus:**
Wer in diesem Modus agiert, ist in Sicherheit und das zu garantieren ist juristisch mutig, wenn man dafür einstehen muss. Die Sicherheit kann dabei inhärent (Bergsteiger bleibt zu Hause) oder maßnahmebedingt sein (Berg wurde planiert).

**Gesicherter Modus:**
Es wurden aktiv maßgebliche Sicherheitsvorkehrungen getroffen, damit kein Unfall passiert. (Fensterputzer wurde angeseilt und trägt Sturzhelm). Damit ist man wohl juristisch auf der sicheren Seite, wenn man nichts falsch gemacht hat.

**Abgesicherter Modus:**
Das „Ab“ steht für *abgrenzend*, damit es, nachdem etwas passiert ist, nicht noch schlimmer kommt, also verwandt mit Notmaßnahmemodus. Seltener ist mit „Ab“ jedoch auch *umfassend* gemeint.

Im Notfall werden Fehler in Deutschland eher verziehen, da man ja nicht vorbereitet sein konnte. Ich habe gehört, dass das in den USA anders sein soll. Da soll sich ein Arzt schon einmal vor der Hilfeleistung drücken, weil er juristische Konsequenzen fürchtet. Weiß jemand, ob das stimmt?

Bei kommerziellen Betriebssystemen könnte *abgesichert* auch bedeuten „Geheimdienst ist zugeschaltet und passt auf“.

Comment: Interessanter Gedanke! Ich hatte gar nicht an den rechtlichen Aspekt gedacht, aber das leuchtet mir sehr ein.

Answer (score 11):

Der sogenannte "abgesicherte Modus" soll Windows (und im Nachgang auch andere OSs) vor Startproblemen schützen, welche durch fehlerhafte Treiber, etc. zustande kommen. Daher sichert dieser Modus Windows gegen Probleme ab, macht Windows aber nicht unbedingt sicherer (außer in dem Sinne, dass durch das Nicht-Ausführen von AutoStart-Programmen einige Schädlinge, wie beispielsweise die beliebten BKA-Trojaner, nicht gestartet werden).

"Sicherer Modus" würde mit Sicherheit im Englischen auch nicht "Safe Mode" sondern "Secure Mode" heißen.

Comment: -1 wegen des letzten Absatzes. „safe“ und „secure“ haben im Englischen unterschiedliche Bedeutungen, die im Deutschen aber beide von „sicher“ getragen werden. Der Unterschied hat aber nichts mit „sicher“ vs. „abgesichert“ zu tun. Der Modus heißt im englischen „safe“, weil nicht vor Attacken, sondern vor Fehlern geschützt werden soll. Im Gegensatz dazu soll der moderne „Secure Boot“ vor Attacken und Linux, aber nicht vor Schlamperei schützen.

Comment: Und genau das habe ich doch auch gesagt? Der "Sichere Modus" (im Sinne von "Schutz von Attacken") würde im Englischen mit Sicherheit "Secure Mode" heißen, nicht "Safe Mode" - warum das ein -1 erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: Weil „Sicherer Modus“ eben „Schutz vor Attacken“ oder „Schutz vor Fehlern“ bedeuten kann. Es würde im Englischen also je nach Bedeutung so oder so übersetzt werden.