# Safety and Security Manager - How to translate to German?

Tags: translation, meaning, english-to-german, vocabulary

Ich muss "Safety and Security Manager" auf Deutsch übersetzen.

> Sicherheits- und Sicherheitsmanager?

Wie übersetze ich `Safety` und `Security` als zwei separate Wörter?

Comment: Siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/weshalb-spricht-man-vom-abgesicherten-modus-und-nicht-vom-sicheren-modus-in/ oder http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58630/what-is-the-correct-use-of-safety-and-security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wörtlich (so gut wie) übersetzt, wäre es

> Verantwortlicher für Sicherheit vor Unfällen und Angriffen

Das würde aber heute kaum noch jemand sagen. Je nach Akzeptanz von Anglizismen wären

> Manager von Betriebssicherheit und Security
>
> Sicherheitsverantwortlicher und Chef der Security
>
> Chef der Betriebssicherheit und Schutzabteilung

Wobei der Begriff `Schutzabteilung` im letzten Beispiel durch den Missbrauch durch die NSDAP leider unbrauchbar wurde.

Comment: Du hast so Recht, es werden an deutschen Fachhochschulen Studiengänge im Fach "Safety and Security Management" angeboten. Das wird dort überhaupt nicht übesetzt. Vielleicht liegt es daran, dass man für die Arbeit im Sicherheitsdienst und Objektschutz bislang nicht unbedingt studieren musste.

Comment: _Werkschutz_? Geht natürlich nur, wenn es auch tatsächlich eine größere Einrichtung ist.

Comment: @Takkat Die Notwendigkeit eines Studiums in Sicherheitsdienst und Objektschutz richtet sich vermutlich nach den Ansprüchen des Arbeitsgebers. Für die entsprechende Abteilung bei deutschen Botschaften braucht man schon eine polizeiliche Ausbildung.